# Drill down in excel while exporting the data from Tableau crosstab to excel

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I have created a Tableau dashboard which has certain drill down. I am exporting  the data from Tableau to excel using Export to crosstab option. Only the data gets copied but not the hierarchy.Is there a way by which I can not only copy the data but also its hierarchy to excel.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are selecting all of the data you want before clicking "export to crosstab" (ctrl click to select multiple fields).

Alternatively i would create a sheet with the desired data, upload it and then use a trick like this -> http://www.vizwiz.com/2014/03/the-greatest-tableau-tip-ever-exporting.html